# Service Cloud field "PersonMailingAddress" not available in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, fields, field-level-security, data-synchronization

We have set the Marketing Cloud Connector with Service Cloud, and when i want to select fields in the Account Object I do not find the PersonMailingAddress.
The field is a combination of the mailing city, mailing country ..etc

I have already checked the security level of the field and it's visible for Sys administrators, and of course my Marketing Cloud Connect user is a sys admin.

Does anyone know where the problem could be ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you know Address is compound field on crm side. Compound fields are accessible only through the SOAP API, REST API, and Apex. The compound versions of fields aren’t accessible anywhere in the Salesforce user interface.(Ref:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_limitations.htm)

One way to solve the problem is: create a formula field for individual parts of compound field , and then sync those formula fields. do remember that formula field will sync only when last modified on the record is changed(Ref : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5).

In the above way you will have
personmailingaddress -- personmailingstreet, personmailingPostalCode,personmailingCity etc

create formule fields like  personmailingstreet==> personmailingstreet_copy, personmailingPostalCode==>personmailingPostalCode_copy,personmailingCity==>personmailingCity_copy

sync the copy fields and then join them in sql or amscript in marketing cloud. .

Thanks
Shekhar